# When is it appropriate to discuss switching from a contractor to permanent employee?

Tags: employer-relations

I have a temporary work position lasting six months. The contract will end in about 3 months from now. My boss mentioned last month that if I show what I have to give I might get a permanent position at the company. I really want that.

I have been performing at my top to deliver work tasks fast and accurate with high quality. I'm socializing with the colleagues and with every task that I have experience of or not I'm learning what I don't know and delivering to the top of what I learned.

I want to discuss the next steps of switching to a permanent employee with my boss, but I don't know when to bring it up. It has been a month. Should I wait for my boss to approach it, and if not, how should I decide when to bring it up with him?

Comment: Your question is very broad—what you need to say or do to get the permanent position is completely dependent on your relationship with your boss. Can you edit your question to talk more about the factors that might be preventing you from getting the permanent job?

Comment: Hey Justin, and welcome to [workplace.se]. Right now you are asking 4 different questions so it's a bit hard to determine what you are actually trying to ask. Are you wondering *when* you should ask? *How* you should ask? An [edit] to focus on a single problem will help get better answers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @jmac Just edited the question. Please review it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Justin! It's still not clear why you think that just asking isn't going to work in this case. You talk about politics and bullying colleagues. Are you somehow worried that just sitting down with your boss and asking him about the permanent position won't work? If so, how? Right now the story seems to be that you are on a 6 month contract, had a discussion after 2 months about becoming permanent, it is now 1 month later (and there are 3 months left), so I don't see the issue with bringing it up or why you'd be hesitant. Could you clarify?

Comment: @jmac This seem straight forward to you. So, please go ahead and make it an answer. It could be accepted if it's a match for my situation. You might be right to just sit down and have the talk with the boss. I didn't even know I could do this! I have my questions, you have your questions. We all have our questions because we are at different levels in life.

Comment: @Justin, your question was put [on hold](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) so I can't answer it even if I wanted. I made another [edit] to it to try to make it clearer what you're asking, and get it reopened. Hopefully the answer to this question will help you based on what you said in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is a chance of possible permanent employment and your boss is letting you know this is your chance to show your interest and prove yourself.  The decision could be delayed up to a few weeks before your contract ends.  Once, I was in the last week of a contract when they extended my role with a full time one.

What you should do is continue working hard and showing enthusiasm for the job.  Show that you can fit into the team smoothly, and follow your boss's direction without conflict or abrasion.  This may be as obvious as completing all your tasks exceptionally, but also going above and beyond by staying late occasionally or coming in early.

Be the first one in and last one out, and even those that don't know what you're working on will assume you're a super hard worker.  Your boss's peers who don't even know you will ask about you to him.

And finally, open the dialog with your boss that you're interested in full time employment, and ask what the chances are that it can happen after your 3 months working.  Do not repeatedly pester him with this topic, but check in once every few weeks if he has heard anything more about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer that you are going to like but the company will either employ you when your contract ends or they will not. If you have been there for six months and there has been tentative interest in retaining you as an employee, then you may be hired. There are, however, no guarantees.

At this point, simply continuing doing what you are is probably the best that you can do in this situation. Also, staying out of the internal politics of the business can be useful. It will prevent you  from saying or doing something which might be used to prevent your being hired.

It might be advisable for you to continue to look for alternate employment options and not count on this company as being your permanent place of employment. That way, while you may be offered employment, your future options will remain open.

Answer (score -1):

IMO you should just keep doing what you're doing and wait. You still have some time. As the deadline draws near, try to finish up a piece of work very nicely and talk over that work with your boss - then slowly try to move the conversation towards the subject of permanent employment, based on your excellent performance (but don't sound boastful, just sincere and gratified that you're able to do good work and make a contribution.)

But, take it easy on socializing with co-workers - you are exposing yourself to potential competitors or enemies. Don't be a loner but mix only with great moderation and selectivity - 'keep your powder dry'.

Also, don't look like you're **trying too hard**, even if you are. In your situation, keeping a low profile might be better.