# How to ask my boss to hire me permanently?

Tags: employer-relations

I joined this great company to cover maternity leave for 15 months contract. Four months before end of my contract, I asked my manager about my potential in the company, she was unsure since she is not very certain if the person will come back or not. Finance department is very lean (only 3 and and according to what they said, head office wont approve a new head count). However, during my time, my manager accepted to manage a second department (marketing) along with finance. She offered to extend my contract for 2 extra months where she could have the returning person get trained on work that is finance/marketing interrelated. As soon as my contract extension was approved from head office and was given to me, I asked her the following: does the return of the person on mat leave mean that I have no potential to stay in this company? Her answer was, "you never know, maybe you will stay as strictly finance person and the other person finance/marketing person". That person returned and she is getting trained. I'm confused as how to bring back to my manager what she said to me and inquire about the possibility to be permanent. I really love working for this company and I only have 2 months left; but afraid if I ask it will make me look so desperate. My friends tell me if she's thinking to hire me permanently, she would have talked to me about it. I'm very confused. Need advice....

Comment: Related - http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/42919/from-contract-to-permanent-same-company-is-it-absurd-to-ask-whatever-you-or, http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19930/when-is-it-appropriate-to-discuss-switching-from-a-contractor-to-permanent-emplo

Comment: @BinaryBazooka, Thanks. The problem is staying till the end of my contract and working as a fiend will be in my way to find another job! Usually employers want to hire immediately, at the most 2 weeks!! That's why I feel like going to her and say, hey, give me a a candid answer as yes there is possibility of being permanent or there is not....so I could focus better on my job search. I work like a fiend anyway...help

Answer (score 3):

She would have talked to you about it by now, the words "you never know" is a bad sign. Sounds like she didn't know whether the other person was going to come back from maternity or not, she may also be waiting to see if she can continue doing the work she did before she had a kid now with a kid.

My advice, if you really want the job work it like a fiend, prove it in the next 2 months, show them that keeping you around would be an 'asset' to the company. If you can't do that then you should at least maintain what you are doing now while spending those 2 months talking to other places, just don't let the current place you work suffer because of it.

Comment: Temporary working overly hard seems like a bad idea, they will expect you'll keep doing that after being permanently hired.

Comment: @Killian First, no one is saying 'slack off' why would you do that? Second how new are you to this industry? And what is your industry? Cause in the real world, people who bond and invest in people don't just want to 'let them go' because they aren't working themselves into the grave everyday. I've gotten several jobs doing this, in some of them they have even told me to 'tone it down now, you've got the job and we now know you can do it'. You don't have to 'kill' yourself, you have 2 months to put it in there heads that they want to keep you around - treat it like an interview